# How do I find the average number of a count in SQL? How do I find % in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking for the average number of items per trailer_id.

If possible I'd love to know what percent of item's have their own trailer (bulk items that don't fit in one of the boxes) and then of trailers that have >1 item how many on average are linked to that trailer.

I have what I think is giving me the average # of items (trkg_id) per trailer (str_lod_trlr_id)?

```
select str_lod_trlr_id, avg(item)
from
(
select str_lod_trlr_id ,count(trkg_id) as item
from tablename group by str_lod_trlr_id) a
group by str_lod_trlr_id
```

How could I find the % of items that have their own str_lod_trlr_id?

Comment: for uniq relationship ur item will only have one uniq str_lod_trlr_id. in ur inner query if count = 1 then its uniq str_lod_trlr_id and u can count total number of str_lod_trlr_id and number of str_lod_trlr_id with only 1 items and find a %

Answer (score 1):

As @Pratik Patil mentioned in the comments:

For **unique** relationship, your `item` will only have one unique `str_lod_trlr_id` in your **inner query** if `count = 1` then it is unique `str_lod_trlr_id`.

You can count the **total number** of `str_lod_trlr_id` and number of `str_lod_trlr_id` with only **1 item** and find a **percentage**.

Posting the answer as *community wiki* for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.